# how to handle infinite loop process when using proc_open

Tags: php, proc-open

I use proc_open to execute a program created by c language.

I was using file for the "stdout".

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("file", "/tmp/example.output"),
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/example.error", "a")
);
```

Everything is fine when I was executing good program but problem occurred when I was executing infinite loop program like the code below :

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    while(1){
        printf("Example");
    }
    return 0
}
```

File example.output will make my hard disk full. So I need to delete the file and restart my computer. My question is how to handle something like this?

Thanks :)

Comment: How about having a time restriction? (if you really don't want to remove your `<infy loop>`

Comment: What did you expect would happen when running an infinite loop like that?

Comment: If there is any infinity loop in any program, fix it first.

Comment: hjpotter92: i set time restriction too, so when the time limit exceeded, system will kill the proc_open process

cillosis: i hope i can kill the proc_open process and save my hardisk space :D

Shiplu: actually the infinite loop program is a input from user. so i need to handle this thing

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is slaughter the offending process without prejudice using [`proc_terminate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php) (but you can be polite and allow it to run for a while first, in effect imposing a time limit for it to complete).

For example:

```
$proc = proc_open(...);
sleep(20); // give the process some time to run
$status = proc_get_status($proc); // see what it's doing
if($status['running']) {
    proc_terminate($proc); // kill it forcefully
}
```

Don't forget to clean up any handles you still have in your hands afterwards.

Comment: i try something like that before, something like "jerhee" say at http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php#81353.
moreover i delete the example.output file after do that using system(). but my harddisk still become full. any idea?

Comment: @SunuPinasthikaFajar: No, you need to do your own debugging, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, but i will try your advice :). Maybe i will found something.